# How to convert date to hours from now using moment js

Tags: node.js, timestamp, momentjs

I have the following data `2020-07-06T02:46:57.883+00:00.` How do I convert it using moment js to `5 hours ago`. for example. I used the following code but it doesnot work.

```
moment('2020-07-06T02:46:57.883+00:00.', "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();
```

but it is not working correctly

Comment: Have you tried: `moment('2020-07-06T02:46:57.883+00:00').fromNow();` ?

Comment: no i didnot let me check

Comment: thanks that works fine. do you mind if you write the answer so i can check it

Comment: Glad that I could help.. If my solution has worked for you, kindly accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to achieve two outcomes through single command.

Ideally, if you want to first format the date and then use the `fromNow()` method, I would suggest the following way:

```
const date = moment('2020-07-06T02:46:57.883+00:00');
const formatedDate = date.format('YYYYMMDD');
const time = date.fromNow();
```

OR You can chain these operations

```
const time =  moment('2020-07-06T02:46:57.883+00:00').fromNow();
```

Note: `format()` method returns a `string`, fromNow() cannot be chained to format method's response.